# Regarding 何と言うか、というのがある

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, syntax, set-phrases

Regarding this bit,

> 日本人がアメリカ人によく聞かれて困る質問の一つに、”How are you?" は日本語で何と言うか、というのがある

I'm guessing the meaning is something along the lines of
"One of the troubling questions that Japanese are asked often by Americans is how to say "How are you" in japanese. "

Is the 何と言うか the same なんというか that's used when you're not sure how to phrase something, like:

> A: みきちゃんは、あんたの彼女でしょう？ B: う～ん、彼女というか、友達というか、なんというか・・・

or is it translated as literally "what to say?"

also could you break down というのがある's grammar or what it means in this context.

these phrases aren't on the jisho sentence database so having a hard time with them

Comment: Oh hey, I recognize this sentence from "An Integrated Approach to Intermediate Japanese"!

Comment: that's right! I started it after finishing genki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is good!

If you do a complete *literal* translation it would be:

One of the questions that Americans ask Japanese is the question of, how do you say 'How are you?' in Japanese.

In this case the 何と言うか literally means "how is (it) said" where (it) refers to "How are you?".

The というのがある means "there is [this question]" referring to the block before it of ”How are you?" は日本語で何と言うか.

Maybe thinking of it in sections can help?

> ***日本人がアメリカ人によく聞かれて困る質問の一つに***、”How are you?" は日本語で何と言うか、***というのがある***

and

> "How are you?" は日本語で何と言うか

Comment: What's the purpose of 「に」at the end of 「 日本人がアメリカ人によく聞かれて困る質問の一つに」? 
What comes to my mind is 「 質問[しつもん]に ○○を答[こた]える」, but the original is different.